# Java memory leaks - Cleared upon program termination?

Tags: java, memory, memory-leaks

This seems like a yes or no question, and I would have expected it to be answered somewhere but I certainly can't find it. Memory leaks in java don't happen as often as as say developing in a language like C or C++, but they can happen.

Most OS will clear memory allocated upon a program's termination, with exception to certain cases like shared memory. Is this still true for when the JVM exits? If I inadvertently create a memory leak in Java will it be cleared by either the JVM or a Linux or Windows OS?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes,all memory will be released after JVM terminated.

Comment: and the same for open file handles, network sockets and the like (but it is still good practice to actively close those when done)

Comment: That answer is a bit idealistic.  There's potential for a leak with JNI, Unsafe calls, off-heap caches, etc.

Comment: @spudone: Really? At least as far as in-process memory is concerned, won't the OS reliably release all of that after the process exits?

Comment: JNI could possibly leak, yes. Other in-process memory could be all released even there is a heap crash. Just restart jvm, all should be released.

Comment: @Thilo in Linux it usually cleans up although running it privileged all bets are off.  Also a leak as a regular user could bring the system to its knees by digging into swap.  Windows... I have no idea, depends on the version.